# I want to use AkkaSpec in (Akka 2.3.14)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka

I want to use AkkaSpec in (Akka 2.3.14)
I'm trying to make TCP-file-IO using actor, sbt, intellij.

I wrote the dependency in build.sbt like below code

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.14",
)

They can import "akka.testkit" but when I "import akka.testkit.AkkaSpec" in my scala file, it can't.

How to use AkkaSpec in akka??? Please help me. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

AkkaSpec is not part of the released artifacts (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/Op1Amu3bItM)), but you could copy the [source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/testkit/AkkaSpec.scala).